# C++ Comparing RHS to LHS of N expressions

Tags: c++

I need to determine whether LHS of an simple expression equals its RHS. The input consists of an integer N, and then N lines of expressions. The output also consists of N lines, whether the expression is correct or not (output `CORRECT` or `WRONG`).

So I attempted to write a for loop for N lines of input, for (int i=1; i<=n; ++i), but I have no idea what else to include inside the for loop.

Also how do you verify whether the equation's LHS equals its RHS?

Comment: The answer to your "also question" is what you put in the loop. You started at the wrong end - in order to solve multiple instances of a problem, you first solve the problem once, then wrap the solution in a loop.

Comment: It's very difficult to even give hints about how to solve the actual problem since you haven't mentioned any specifics about what a "simple expression" is.

Comment: Please limit the scope to a single focused question and specify what parts of evaluating the expression you are having trouble with

Answer (score 1):

For input like this (assuming it is saved in file "equation_list.txt"):

```
3 
3 = 1 + 2
3 = 3 + 2 
3 * 9 = 26 + 1
```

The following code would generate console output like this:

```
CORRECT
WRONG
CORRECT
```

The `for (int i = 1; i <= std::stoi(equations[0]); i++)` in function `int main()` is the loop you have mentioned in your question. Before the loop happens, there are some file and string manipulations.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#include "exprtk.hpp"

bool check_equation(const std::string LHS, const std::string RHS)
{
    typedef exprtk::expression<double>     expression_t;
    typedef exprtk::parser<double>             parser_t;

    expression_t expression;
    parser_t parser;

    // Calculate LHS's value.
    parser.compile(LHS, expression);
    double LHS_result = expression.value();

    // Calculate RHS's value.
    parser.compile(RHS, expression);
    double RHS_result = expression.value();

    // Check if the difference of these two results is less than a very small 
    // value EPSILON.
    // This is the proper way in C++ to check equation of double values.
    // "if (LHS_result == RHS_result)" is not reliable.
    if (abs(LHS_result - RHS_result) < std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("equation_list.txt");
    std::stringstream buffer;

    // Read the equation list from file, saving into buffer.
    if (file)
    {
        buffer << file.rdbuf();
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "equation file does not exist!";
    }

    // Split the equations to individual ones (delimiter is '\n' (newline symbol)), 
    // saving into a vector.
    std::vector<std::string> equations;
    std::string s;

    while (getline(buffer, s, '\n'))
    {
        equations.push_back(s);
    }

    // Loop the vector to check the correctness of each equation. 
    // equations[0] is the number of equations (the first line in input).
    for (int i = 1; i <= std::stoi(equations[0]); i++)
    {
        // Again, using the previous technique, split this equation by 
        // delimiter '=', saving the result (i.e. LHS and RHS) into a vector.
        std::stringstream individual_equation(equations[i]);

        std::vector<std::string> parts;
        std::string s;

        // Assuming each line of equations has one and only one '=' symbol. Checking omitted.
        while (getline(individual_equation, s, '=')) 
        {
            parts.push_back(s);
        }

        // Now, parts[0] is LHS, and parts[1] is RHS.
        // Check if LHS equals to RHS.
        if (check_equation(parts[0], parts[1]) == true)
        {
            std::cout << "CORRECT" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "WRONG" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The tricky part of your problem is to simulate the mathematical calculation of a string input (the LHS and the RHS). This is not as intuitive as it seems at first sight. I suggest to use external library to address this calculation (see `#include "exprtk.hpp"` and function `bool check_equation(const std::string LHS, const std::string RHS)` in the code). This library is called **ExprTk**. You can find more information about ExprTk in http://partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html .

If you plan to implement the mathematical calculation simulation by yourself, I suggest you to start by looking into [**Polish Notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), which is a computer-convenient way of reading expressions.

Just to provide an example of Polish Notation. `a + b / c - d * e` is human-convenient way of reading expressions. The computer-convenient way is to read it *functionally* as `sub(add(a, div(b, c)), mul(d, e))`. After replacing the function names with operand symbols, it then becomes the Polish Notation `-+a/bc*de`.

Finally, the data structure [**Binary Tree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) would become handy in practice, where all the operands stay on leaf nodes and all the operators stay on non-leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

1. Define a data type for representing expressions.
2. Write a function that determines whether two such expressions are equal.

   - Test it with hardcoded data.
3. Write a function that reads one expression.

   - Test it with hardcoded data.
4. Use the functions from items 2 and 3 to read two expressions and compare them.
   Print the appropriate response.
5. Wrap a loop around item 4.